# StackExchange OAuth and OpenID Authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, openid

I have been having a goosey around the login functions of stackexchange, and I have noticed that depends on what you click, it adjusts a form with either OAuth information, or OpenID information in the form of the query which submits the form to a script inside of stackexchange, and I was wondering if anyone had the information for how the script would communicate with that particular service and use the returned information to login, as well as fetching additional information about that account from the service.

If anyone has any scripts or snippets, PHP would be preferred.

Comment: -1 as your question is difficult to understand. eg what does 'goosey' mean?

Comment: There are various libraries out there that can perform OAuth/OpenID authentication.  Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @vascowhite goosey, having a gander at the source of it to find out what makes it tick. Cant help it, those are words I use in honest conversation, and i have been clouted for it in the past.

Comment: @afuzzyllama indeed, i have been looking but there seems to be such a variety, im not sure which one is best

Comment: +1 for 'goosey', vascowhite is just being pernickety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Janrain OpenID Libraries](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled) are pretty good.  They have a few quirks when it comes to extending them, but I think for your purposes they will be fine.

Facebook does NOT do OpenID.  For Facebook you will need to use a different library (and that is something I have not done, so I cannot comment on it).

Comment: Cool, cheers bud. I have had some experience with Facebook login and thats worked fine. I thought that maybe facebook used OAuth because the OAuth_Server is defined as "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize"

Comment: [OpenID != OAuth](http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing), so while Facebook might use OAuth, they do not conform to the OpenID standard that Google and others do.

Comment: That was sort of the question I had, a class that can handle both depending upon the OAuth Server Address, then moving onto determining how the user will be authenticated

Comment: Are you trying to access data from the user's account or have a single sign on solution?

Comment: yeah, a single sign on solution is what im going for, but it would be good to be able to get some of the details, such as contact information and language, maybe some other things too, but not sure what would be available